# How to print the values of variables in a JMeter bean shell assertion

Tags: web-services, api, jmeter, verification, assertion

Using Jmeter, I'm passing values to a webservice through a REST API. On Success the API updates the values to a mongo DB.
While Asserting using JMeter BeanShell Assertion..I want to display the values sent in the Request and values Stored in the DB.

Im Using the below Script..

```
String req_data="${Request_Configuration}";
String res_data="${mongo_db_Configuration}";


if(res_data.equalsIgnoreCase(req_data)){
   Failure=false;
   FailureMessage = "Data stored in DB is correct";
   System.out.println("ReqData="+req_data);
   System.out.println("ResData="+res_data);
}
else{
   Failure = true;
   FailureMessage = "Data Stored in DB is NOT correct";
   System.out.println("ReqData="+req_data);
   System.out.println("ResData="+res_data);
}
```

Im Just not able to Print ReqData and ResData. Please help out.

Comment: Why can't you print them? Does the output look odd or do you get an error?

Comment: Request_Configuration : Value Sent in API Request , mongo_db_Configuration : Value fetched from mongodb using a MongoDB Query and processed using a BSF PostProcessor.

Comment: The Assertion result says : Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Data Stored in DB is NOT correct.  But does not print the values in the Assertion Result.

Comment: I don't see an assert in your code nor any "Assertion result". Please add the missing pieces to your question.

Answer (score 10):

Use `log.info()`

**Example**

```
log.info("myVariable: " + vars.get("myVariable"));
```

---

My use case:

I did use the following code snipped in a `BeanShell Assertion` within my `HTTP Request`-sampler to print out my three variables `id`, `type` and `value`:

```
log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": " + SampleLabel + ": id: " + vars.get("id"));
log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": " + SampleLabel + ":  +-type: " + vars.get("type"));
log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": " + SampleLabel + ":  +-value: " + vars.get("value"));
```

Printing also the built-in `SampleLabel` variable gives you the hint from which sampler you logged this information.

Answer (score 9):

You have a problem in your script. In Beanshell you cannot access variables like `${Request_Configuration}`, you need to use `vars.get("Request_Configuration")` instead.

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance for current context.

So your Beanshell Assertion code should look as follows:

```
String req_data=vars.get("Request_Configuration");
String res_data=vars.get("mongo_db_Configuration");


if(res_data.equalsIgnoreCase(req_data)){
   Failure=false;
   FailureMessage = "Data stored in DB is correct";
   System.out.println("ReqData="+req_data);
   System.out.println("ResData="+res_data);
}
else{
   Failure = true;
   FailureMessage = "Data Stored in DB is NOT correct";
   System.out.println("ReqData="+req_data);
   System.out.println("ResData="+res_data);
}
```

I would also suggest using `log.info()` instead of `System.out.println()` as in that case results will go to *jmeter.log* file and won't be "eaten" by exceeding screen buffer size.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting and various JMeter API objects exposed to Beanshell explanation.